# Catch Exception inside IASyncResult for a Ping

Tags: c#, .net

and Happy new year :)

I need to check connectivity of computers in my company. If online, I retrieve some infos on these, unlock some buttons, etc. I need essentially to ping computers by their hostname. After some Google searchs, I found the below code. But, in case where the hostname doesn't exists or don't ping, I have an exception which I am unable to catch. I need the reply to come as fast as possible, and to not freeze my UI.

```
public static bool GetPing(string hostname)
    {
        if (hostname == null || hostname == string.Empty)
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool pingable = false;

        try
        {
            Func<PingReply> pingDelegate = () => new Ping().Send(hostname);
            IAsyncResult result = pingDelegate.BeginInvoke(r => pingDelegate.EndInvoke(r), null); // The exception comes here

            //wait for thread to complete
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(100);
            pingable = result.IsCompleted;

            Console.WriteLine("ping ok : " + pingable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex.Message);
        }

        return pingable;
    }
```

I also tried much more "classic" approachs, but anwsers are way too long if the ping is KO.

The above code is simply called like that :

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string hostname = tb1.Text;

        var IsOnline = GetPing(hostname);

        if (IsOnline)
        {
            // Hostname ping ok
        }
        else
        {
            // Hostname do not ping
        }
    }
```

Finally, when pinging a hostname, the reply come quickly (true or false), but if False, few seconds later my app crashes with message "Exception not handled in user code"...
Is anyone could help me please ?

Comment: Why don't you use [SendPingAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_NetworkInformation_Ping_SendPingAsync_System_String_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Net_NetworkInformation_PingOptions_) ? The entire `GetPing` method would be replaced with `var isOnline=await ping.SendPingAsync(hostName,someTimeout);`

Comment: There is no way (in my opinion) to change or manipulate the exception time, this means some exceptions might be raised in few milli sconds while other need minutes or seconds, you cannot influence the network, proxies, firewalls...etc. and everything else that is involved in the network.

What you can do is this:
You should/must make your GUI independent of the exception time, you can e.g. make a thread that pings the computers in the background and sends events/messages to the GUI when ever a ping is completed. This way your users don't wait for an unpredictable time

Comment: Bear in mind that just because a computer responded to a ping in the *very recent past* (the information you can reason about once you get a successful ping response), there's no guarantee that it'll respond to any more advanced network-based access in the *very near future*, i.e. in your next line of code. If you need to interact with the machine, skip the ping and just *try* to start interacting with it. You need to write code that deals with *that* communication breaking down part-way through *anyway*. Ping just adds more unnecessary roundtrips.

Comment: Thank's for replys. Damien, it was a good advice indeed, but for some other reasons, I need this Ping function :). Finally, I opted for Panagiotis' advice, and the pingAsync does the trick, with some tweaking :)